# using Riverpods NotifierProvider with a "State"-class

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have an appstate in a class **State2** with a property **pos**.

```
class State2 {
  double pos = 0.9;
  String anotherProerty = "anotherproperty";
}
```

Using a Riverpod NotifierProvider, I want to use the pos property for a slider in a ConsumerWidget.
Unfortunately that does not work as I implemented it. It is not possible to move the slider.

As a comparison I implemented a second Slider with a "simple" NotifierProvider, which works fine.

Any idea what´s wrong?

Here is my code:

```
class Position1 extends Notifier<double> {
  @override
  double build() {
    return 0.1;
  }

  void updatePos(double newPos) {
    state = newPos;
  }
}

final position1Provider = NotifierProvider<Position1, double>(Position1.new);

class State2 {
  double pos = 0.9;
  String anotherProerty = "anotherproperty";
}

class State2Notifier extends Notifier<State2> {
  @override
  State2 build() {
    return State2();
  }

  void updatePos(double pos) {
    state.pos = pos;
  }
}

final state2Provider =
    NotifierProvider<State2Notifier, State2>(State2Notifier.new);

class RiverpodExampe1 extends ConsumerWidget {
  const RiverpodExampe1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final pos1 = ref.watch(position1Provider);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Riverpod Sample 2"),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text("Pos1: $pos1"),
            Slider(
                value: pos1,
                onChanged: (newPosition) {
                  ref.read(position1Provider.notifier).updatePos(newPosition);
                }),
            Slider(
                value: ref.watch(state2Provider).pos,
                onChanged: (newPosition) {
                  ref.read(state2Provider.notifier).updatePos(newPosition);
                })
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use immutable state instead https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/why_immutability#using-immutable-state

Comment: @DhafinRayhan Thanks! Do you think, that's the reason, why it doesn´t work. The doku doesn´t require immutable, they "only" recommend it.

Comment: It is recommended, because if you don't use immutable you have to manually call `notifyListeners()`, as demonstrated in https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/change_notifier_provider

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I made a Version with a immutable and it works fine, thanks!
I also tried another mutable version with notifyListeners(), but Notifier doesn´t have a notifyListeners() method.
I think you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Wasn't sure about writing an answer since I thought there should be a similar answer somewhere, but here we go

Comment: There is a `ref` property inside `Notifier` and you could call `ref.notifyListeners();` after mutating the mutable model. The `notifyListeners()` is from the `Ref` object, not `Notifier`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a property of the state (like `state.pos = pos`), the notifier won't notify its listeners because technically the instance of the state is still the same (only the property that has changed). This is why it's preferred to use **immutable state** instead, to prevent these kinds of errors.

It is recommended to use package like [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed), which provides a `copyWith` method that is very useful when you need to create a new state based on the previous state with a small change to its properties.

You can then update the state by doing this:

```dart
void updatePos(double pos) {
  state = state.copyWith(pos: pos);
}
```

---

It is possible to create a notifier provider that supports mutable state, as shown in the [ChangeNotifierProvider](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/change_notifier_provider) example. But using [NotifierProvider](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/notifier_provider) with immutable state is preferred.

Read more about immutability: https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/why_immutability